# Android Java String code optimization needed

Tags: android, string, performance, indexof

I have issue with parsing html data. Java's String.indexof() is extremelly slow. Could anyone suggest any solutions to significantly speed it up?

```
                      while (counter2 <= found)
                    {
                        number = Integer.toString(counter2);
                        start = page.indexOf("<result" + number + ">") + 8 + number.length();
                        end = page.indexOf("</result" + number + ">");
                        if (start > 0 && end > 0)
                        {
                            buffer = page.substring(start, end);
                        }
                        page = page.substring(end, page.length());
                        start = buffer.indexOf("<word>") + 6;
                        end = buffer.indexOf("</word>");
                        if (start > 0 && end > 0)
                        {
                            Word = buffer.substring(start, end);
                        }
                        start = buffer.indexOf("<vocabulary>") + 12;
                        end = buffer.indexOf("</vocabulary>");
                        if (start > 0 && end > 0)
                        {
                            Dictionary = buffer.substring(start, end);
                        }

                        start = buffer.indexOf("<id>") + 4;
                        end = buffer.indexOf("</id>");
                        if (start > 0 && end > 0)
                        {
                            ID = buffer.substring(start, end);
                        }

                        sqlDriver.createDictionaryWord("Wordlist", ID, Word, Dictionary);
                       // counter = counter + 1;
                        counter2 = counter2 + 1;

                    }
```

I need to make it work at least 5 times faster somehow. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a [XmlPullParser](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pattern matcher` using regex is quite faster than `indexOf()` for longer Strings (For smaller Strings, `indexOf()` is better than regex). Use your text and a regex to find the index of your String pattern.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

public static void getIndices(String text, Pattern pattern) {

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    matcher.find();
    System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
    System.out.print("End index: " + matcher.end());

}
```

Note that you have to compile your regex to `Pattern` object only once for every regex and so don't put it inside a loop.

Comment: Count you please give me an example to get value between those two

                        start = buffer.indexOf("<vocabulary>") + 12;
                        end = buffer.indexOf("</vocabulary>");

I need value in between of that as string

Comment: Are you parsing an XML content? If so, as Michael as suggested in the comments, you should use [XmlPullParser](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html)

Answer (score 0):

I made xml and used advice to use XmlPullParser. A bit faster, but still on some devices over minute, diring file size 1.7mb. Quite confusing.